# Needs to be serializable bean in sticky session that contains Remot EJB?

Tags: java, serialization, sticky-session

I was trying to find information about java bean needs to be serializable in a sticky session? Seems to be that if contains a @remot EJB must be, but ¿Is this true?

Comment: Not sure, if I understand your question, but typically everything you put in session object must be serializable. Another thing is that you shall not pass around reference to remote business interface.

Comment: a j2ee app works perfectly deployed in  weblogic servlet and beans doesn't implement serializable interface..

Comment: Did you try to add bean into session object?

Comment: is a scope session...so I just trying to understand how it works..

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your last question.